# try-with-resource - finally keyword error on Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following code which yields me a **"Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete TryStatement".**

```
 private synchronized void writeDurationToFile(String sFileName, Date dtStartTime, long lDuration, String sStatus) {

    if(!sRHTimeStamp.isEmpty()) {

        String sFullPath = sFileName + "_" + sRHTimeStamp +  ".csv";

        try {

            if(!Paths.get(sFullPath).toFile().exists()) {

                try(    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(sFullPath);
                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);)  {

                    pw.println("Start\tEnd\tDuration");
                    pw.println(TimeUtils.getTimeStamp(true, dtStartTime) + "," + lDuration + "," + sStatus);
                }

            }else{

                try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(sFullPath, true); PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);)  {

                    pw.println(TimeUtils.getTimeStamp(true, dtStartTime) + "," + lDuration + "," + sStatus);
                }
            }
        } //Here I get the error notification
    }
}
```

Why do I get this error, and how can I write it better to eliminate the duplication of

```
pw.println(TimeUtils.getTimeStamp(true, dtStartTime) + "," + lDuration
+ "," + sStatus);
```

but still use the "try-with-resource" implementation.

I based my code on http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html

Comment: Why did you put your code in a try block if you are not catching any exception?

Comment: `try {..}` is not a try-with-resource statement.

Comment: @Eran I tried to implement this methodology - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html in order to avoid finally and to enforce closing the resources any way. The example shows a usage only of try clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your larger `try` block is not a try-with-resources, but rather a standard try.  It therefore needs to have either a `catch` or `finally` block added to it.

Answer (score 2):

`try {..}` is not a `try-with-resource` statement.

Your `try{...}` may make sense as `try-with-resource` will close resources for you but not handle exceptions thrown during statements execution of the `try` block.

But note that a classic `try` has to be declared with a `finally` or a `catch` statement or both.

Your method `writeDurationToFile()` doesn't throw `IOException` while you code may throw it.
So you should either add it in the method declaration :

```
 private synchronized void writeDurationToFile(String sFileName, Date dtStartTime, long lDuration, String sStatus)  throws IOException
```

and remove the `try{...}` to allow the client code to handle the `IOException`.

Or another way would be catching the exception in the method by completing the `try` statement with a `catch`.
In this way, the client code doesn't need to handle the `IOException` :

```
try { //classic try

      // try-with-resource
      try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(sFullPath);
          PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw))  {
            ...
      }
      ...
      // other try-with-resource
      try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(sFullPath, true);
          PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw))  {
          ...
      }
} 
// catch exceptions thrown in the block/body of the `try-with-resource` statements
catch (IOException e){
   // exception handling
}
```